# Filter rows with unique values on Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, I have hundreds of items like these:

```
   column_a      column_b       column_c       column_d      column_e

r1      200           300            350            400             3
r2      200           300            350            400             1
r3      200           300            350            400             2
r4      100           150            200            300             1
r5      100           150            200            300             2
r6      100           150            200            300             4
```

Rows `r1`, `r2`, and `r3` have the same values in every column except `column_e` as do `r4`, `r5`, and `r6`.

I would like to see only the unique rows with maximum `column_e` value. For example, from the above, I would only see `r1`, which has a maximum `column_e` value of 3 and `r6`, which has a maximum `column_e` value of 4.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the maximum values and you don't care which row it's from, you could:

1. create a pivot table with column_a, column_b, column_c, and column_d in the Row Labels section and column_e in the Values section (change it to show Max rather than Count), or
2. use Subtotal (selecting Max as your function)

Comment: If the row number is required, that could be achieved by adding an ID row (to the data table) and using the index functions on the pivot table.